# Are event listeners in jQuery removed automatically when you remove the element using .html()?

Tags: jquery, events, memory-leaks, unbind

In jQuery if we use `.remove()` for removing some element, then all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

But what happens if we "remove" the elements with `.html()`?

Do we need to unbind all the elements prior to change any html for avoiding memory leaks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they will be removed. jQuery will clean up events etc related to the removed elements. It will NOT copy events if you do something like $(elm1).html($elm2.html())

Answer (score 13):

Yeah, they will be removed even when you use `html()`. The jQuery [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L231) confirms it.

Comment: Thanks Anurag, I know you was the first and you are certifying your answer (+1 for that), but kinghfb need more points, so I will mark his answer as accepted for motivating him, I hope you understand. Thanks !

Comment: At any rate there should be an SO badge for validating your answer with a link to the source code :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit:

- [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/), [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/), etc - all remove listeners
- [`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) **does not** remove listeners
- [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) has parameters letting you decide if data/listeners are copied

So if you want to retain listeners, use `.detach()`.