# jquery similar with .html() but not removing the event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I'm having this code:

```
    <div id="groups">
        <select multiple="multiple" id="availableGroups" name="availableGroups">
          <option >Opt 1</option>
          <option >Opt 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

The `"select"` element has a click event listener which attach to it.

What I'm to do is to change the `$('div#groups')` content with `<p>` element when the user click next button, so I do like this:

```
var $groupContent=$('div#groups').children(); //save the content
$('div#groups').html($("<p>").append("Opt 1"))
```

And if the user click the prev button,I will restore the `"select"` element like this:

```
 $('div#groups').append($groupContent);
```

The problem is the click event listener also has been remove when I'm using `.html()` as stated on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549188/are-event-listeners-in-jquery-removed-automatically-when-you-remove-the-element)

So the question is,is there a workaround I can implement same action like `.html()` without removing the event listener?

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Are you intending to replace all of the content, including the 'select' element, with a paraphraph containing 'Opt 1' as text? Using .html() you are actually replacing all of the contents of <div id="groups">, so you are not just replacing the event hander, but the entire select control as well.

Comment: Stop replacing all the HTML.  Instead, add, modify or delete individual DOM elements directly as needed, thus preserving all event handlers on element which are not deleted.

Comment: also you can save and restore event handlers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the event handler to the parent element like this. It will be preserved. Something like:

```
$("div#groups").on("click", "#availableGroups", yourClickHandler);
```

See the live demo https://jsfiddle.net/nf3wyf21/

Read more about jQuery event delegation [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it work with minor modification and some reference.